# MongoDB "Index Filter" and "Filtered Indexes"

Tags: mongodb

Trying to tell (hint) to mongo which index to use when it see's certain query forms. I could give the cursor a hint, but that would not be helpful when using aggregates starting with a match stage.

To do that, mongo provides the ability to "register" query forms and specify which indexes the query planner can concider. Hoorah thinks I: as that would do just what I'm looking to do.

given a document schema that looks likes this:

```
{ 
   Domain : "google.com",
   LocalPart : "james.bond",
   Status :  5
}
```

and the indexes:

```
{ Status : 1, Domain : 1, LocalPart : 1 }
{ Status : 1 }
```

by registering an Index Filter for the collection:

```
db.runCommand(
   {
      planCacheSetFilter: "testColl",
      query: { Status : 999, "Domain" : "Y" },      
      indexes: [ { Status : 1 } ]
   }
)
```

When I run:

```
testColl.find( { Status : 5, Domain : "google.com" } ).explain()
```

The winning plan uses an index scan of the index:

```
{ Status : 1 }
```

Just as hoped. Life is good. (I know it not really the best index here, but that's the one I want)

But the thing is, index { Status : 1 } is actually a "filtered index" that only contains "Status = 5", so I re-declared the index to  be:

```
{ Status : 1 }, { partialFilterExpression : { Status : 5 }
```

When I re-run the query, the winning plan is now a **collection scan**!!!

I could not find anywhere why or how to get the "Index Filter" make use of "Filtered Indexes".

So the question becomes: is it possible? If so, what's the syntax?

Thanx!

ps: Please keep replies to the topic of "Index Filter" using "Filtered Indexes". Telling me that for the provided example, it's not the most efficient way to do it is irrelevant unless you see a general case and special case golden hammer pattern. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this form of index:

```
{ Domain : 1 }, { partialFilterExpression : { Status : 5 } }
```